# calling a list instance from another class

Tags: python, pyside2

I want to access a list created on my main window based on user selection, on my second window.

the list was created in `MainWindow` under the `on_cc_pick` method. List `creditcards`.

on the second window, I would like to access it on `CreditCardForm`

When i try.`MainWindow.creditcards` or `MainWindow.creditcardsb` it tells me object has no attribute creditcards/b.

When I try doing a global variable under MainWindow Class:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
     creditcards = []
```

it always defaults to an empty list.

here is my code, in essence I want to access the list called `creditcardsb` created on class `MainWindow` under `def on_cc_pick(self,text):` on class `CreditCardForm` under `def savecsv(self):`

```
class AddCreditCard(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(AddCreditCard, self).__init__(parent)
        creditcardform = CreditCardForm(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(creditcardform)

class CreditCardForm(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def savecsv(self):
        **print(MainWindow.creditcardsb)**

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(CreditCardForm, self).__init__(parent) 
        self.addname = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Save')
        self.connect(self.addname,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.savecsv)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):


    def CreateCCForm(self):
        self.addwindow.show()

    def on_cc_pick(self, text):
        NickName = []
        Account = []
        with open(refdirectory + '/' + str(text) + '.csv') as csvDataFile:
            csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
            for row in csvReader:
                NickName.append(row[0])
                Account.append(row[1])

        **creditcardsb = list(zip(NickName,Account))
        self.creditcards = creditcardsb**


    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
        self.pickcard = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        CreditCardNames = ['cc1','cc2','cc3']

        for cc in CreditCardNames:
             self.pickcard.addItem(cc)
        self.addcard = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add Card')
        self.pickcard.activated[str].connect(self.on_cc_pick)
        self.connect(self.addcard, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.CreateCCForm)

        self.addwindow = AddCreditCard(self)
```

These are the imports I am using, not all relatable to my issue:

```
from subprocess import Popen
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import string
import time
import random
import csv
import pandas as pd
from pick import pick
import requests
import re
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog
import os
import pyodbc
from decimal import *
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from datetime import datetime, date
from decimal import Decimal
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: tried, deleting as much code as possible. I am using widgets to trigger a lot of my functions / data

Comment: what time do you call on_cc_pick?

Comment: Updated `self.pickcard.activated[str].connect(self.on_cc_pick)`

Comment: At first I put all of it on it, and I thought your comment meant it was too long. Then I deleted some and clearly missed important parts, I don't know what to show without creating too much noise for the question.

Comment: Partly my request was because its code is too long, but if I had read it is a [mcve] I would have understood correctly and understood the importance of the MCVE, if you have not read it please do it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use static variables since the property you want to transmit depends not on the class but on the objects. So the correct thing is to create a method that updates the data of the window. In addition, assuming that `CreditCardForm` will always be a child of `AddCreditCard`, you can obtain `AddCreditCard` using `parentWidget()` from `CreditCardForm`.

```
import os
import csv
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class AddCreditCard(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AddCreditCard, self).__init__(parent)
        creditcardform = CreditCardForm()
        self.setCentralWidget(creditcardform)
        self._creditcards = []

    def setCreditcards(self, creditcards):
        self._creditcards = creditcards

    def creditcards(self):
        return self._creditcards

class CreditCardForm(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CreditCardForm, self).__init__(parent) 
        self.addname = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Save')
        self.addname.clicked.connect(self.savecsv)
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.addname)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def savecsv(self):
        creditcards = self.parentWidget().creditcards()
        print(creditcards)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
        self.addwindow = AddCreditCard(self)

        self.pickcard = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.pickcard.activated[str].connect(self.on_cc_pick)
        creditcardnames = ['cc1','cc2','cc3']
        self.pickcard.addItems(creditcardnames)

        self.addcard = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add Card')
        self.addcard.clicked.connect(self.addwindow.show)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.addcard)
        lay.addWidget(self.pickcard)

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def on_cc_pick(self, text):
        creditcards = []
        refdirectory = ""
        filename = os.path.join(refdirectory, "{}.csv".format(text))
        with open(filename) as csvDataFile:
            csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
            for row in csvReader:
                creditcards.append((row[0], row[1]))
        self.addwindow.setCreditcards(creditcards)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Wow awesome, thanks so much for your troubles and for re-constructing it on with a pythonic way.

Comment: @DannyCabrera for a next occasion it takes time and provides a [mcve] since we can easily analyze where the problem is or simply reproduce your problem, for example my code is an MCVE, are the necessary imports and do not depend on external things, it is self-sufficient

Comment: got it, I was re-constructing, to post when I saw your answer and it worked with no troubles. Thanks again